# How to compress a string on Haskell?

Tags: haskell, compression

I am starting to learn some commands in Haskell. I have just a basic programming course of basic C for mathematics undergraduates. So, sorry if I can't explain better myself, or if this question is obvious, or too complex, or not good for Haskell.

what I want to do: after producing some random string of size n on a text, compress the string and count its bites.

This example is very much what this functions on Mathematica do: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Compress.html

Comment: Welcome! We'll be better able to help you if you can narrow down your question. Can you pick one specific problem, rather than a large class of them? Can you show how you might like to fit compression into the rest of your program?

Comment: Look at the `zlib` package. You'll probably find suitable functions operate on `Bytestring`s as the appropriate type for binary data.

Comment: @dfeuer, sorry, next time I will pick a specific one. The example i want to do is this one:  after producing some random string of size n on a text , compress the string and count its bites. I will look for the suggestions made here. thanks.

Comment: "Can you show how you might like to fit compression into the rest of your program?" After the compression of the string I would like to count its bites or to print the string in an archive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JuicyPixels' Codec.Picture.Saving.imageToBitmap](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/JuicyPixels-3.3.5/docs/Codec-Picture-Saving.html) will yield a ByteString.
[zlib's Codec.Compression.GZip.compress](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/zlib-0.6.2.1/docs/Codec-Compression-GZip.html) will take that ByteString and make a compressed ByteString.
[base64-bytestring's Data.ByteString.Base64.encode](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base64-bytestring-1.1.0.0/docs/Data-ByteString-Base64.html) will take the compressed ByteString and yield a printable ASCII string similar to Matlab's Compress.

Comment: Requests for library recommendations are [explicitly off-topic on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251134/where-can-i-ask-about-finding-a-tool-library-or-favorite-off-site-resource). Better to vote to close them than to answer them.

Comment: @amalloy sorry, I didn't even know I was asking library recommendations...

Comment: @amalloy the question specifically asks about replicating Mathematica's Compress in Haskell which is the core of my answer. I can remove the library recommendations as they are off-topic.

Comment: @Lostdefinition my answer doesn't answer your question. Did you mark it correct in error? I'll need to delete it to make way for correct answers in that case.

Comment: @AlainO'Dea I think after the edit it's an okay, on-topic question: a Mathematica user might reasonably hope that Haskell can do this out of the box too. The only possible answers, though, are either "No" or a library recommendation, which is kinda a messy situation. I'm not really sure what the best approach here is, but I've retracted my close vote since it seems a reasonable question.

Comment: Definitely a hard call. Thank you!

Comment: @Alain O'Dea, I think you have give me some hints, so I consider an answer.

Comment: I didn't knew I was asking for library recommendations, actually, I didn't even knew this was forbidden here. I will try to be more strict on what I ask.

Comment: Thank you for all your help. Now I will struggle to find a way to know better about this libraries.